# Error on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting an Error on my webpage - only on certain pages:

Here is the error page:

Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error >settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being >viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running >on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote >machines, please create a tag within a "web.config" configuration file >located in the root directory of the current web application. This tag >should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by >modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's >configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
```

And here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="None"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It used to work but now doesnt... And no changes were made to the system...
What could the reason be for this?
Can be be if the .Net framework version has changed?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Go to server and run the site you should get a proper error! or change web config as mentioned to view the error

Comment: Make sure you have right web.config on the server. It may be that you have custom errors off on debug config and on on release config or vice versa.

Comment: Have you migrated from older version of IIS to newer one?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have multiple web.config files in your application.  Multiples annoys .NET/IIS and could be the reason for your edits being "ignored".